# Problem regarding finding work done

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, potential-energy

This problem is given in my physics book. How much work will be done if anyone wants to stack up 12 bricks? Given that each brick is $10 cm$ high and each brick's mass is $2 kg$. ($g=9.8$)

Now in finding my answer I used the mass and height of all the bricks. But in my book they used the mass of all the bricks. But in using the height they used the height of only 11 bricks. So my result is $141.12 J$ and the book's result is $129.36 J$. Why is that?

Comment: The bottom brick is already on the ground and requires no work to place it there.

Comment: @Farcher Well that makes sense. But if don't use its height than why we use its mass?

Comment: You don't. Use @Farcher advice and then calculate for the remainder of **11** bricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are supposed to stack 12 bricks on one another. One brick is unmoved. The centre of mass of 11 bricks is 60 cm or 0.6m above initial level after stacking.

Now, the work done against the force of gravity is:

$W = mg \Delta h  = 2(11)(9.8)(0.6) = 129.36J $

Another method is to calculate work done individually

$W = mg(\Delta h_1+\Delta h_2+\Delta h_3+\Delta h_4+\Delta h_5+\Delta h_6+\Delta h_7+\Delta h_8+\Delta h_9+\Delta h_{10}+\Delta h_{11})$

$\implies W = 2(9.8)(0.1+0.2+0.3+0.4+0.5+0.6+0.7+0.8+0.9+1+1.1)$

$\implies W = 129.36J$

Comment: That really helped a lot.